# Default parameter in typescipt causing compilation error

Tags: typescript

```
type User ={
    readonly id: number,
    name: string,
    greet: (name: string) => void
}

let betterUser: User = {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Masud',
    greet: (name: string = betterUser.name): void => {
        console.log(`Hello ${name}`)
    }
}

betterUser.greet();
```

I'm getting compilation error on last line. But It should be valid though. Can point out where is the problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make `name` optional to make this compile.

```
type User = {
    readonly id: number,
    name: string,
    greet: (name?: string) => void
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvAbwFBW1RECGAJgPYB2ANiFAJaEBcUpArgLYBGSANFjqfixAZxgiaqQDm3HFHF4IwBgAo+AgPxCRY8QEpUAPigA3YrQwBfDBnLyoHYMCTwkDJ8hRRM02gwBMU3vyCUADkALL4cEyEwf7YshDySipBwqISqLbyDoiuAHTJ2gzGtPoePNLYAMZkcMTWueTE4ooABgASEOSNUAAkaMlmLdrlUBYWGHbZefHyitoA3EA)

Comment: thanks a lot. Realized that I have to explicitly make the parameter optional.